# Accessing a $_GET variable whose value contains '&'

Tags: php

What is a good workaround for fields that have '&'? I have a site that is getting stuff via $_GET, but some of the fields are, for example: 'Pants & shorts'... When I put this in a URL it gets all messed up :) Any PHP fix for it? :)

For example:

> http://localhost/clothes/?sex=both&order=newest&time=all&type=Pants%20&%20Shorts

Thank you!

Comment: How do you print that in a URL?

Comment: http://localhost/clothes/?sex=both&order=newest&time=all&type=Pants%20&%20Shorts

Comment: Can you modify the page that is sending in pants & shorts?  If so, just urlencode it -- otherwise, you might have to write your own parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the PHP manual for `urlencode()`
http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php more appropriate I belive. Remember, any href's should be coded with & replaced with &amp; .

Comment: @user247245, `htmlspecialchars` only deals with sanitizing for HTML documents. Even when you `htmlspecialchars` a url to "clean it up" the browser will `urlencode` it when sending it to the server.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

or:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 2):

when writing the url:

```
http://localhost/clothes/<? echo urlencode('pants & shorts'); ?>/
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP seems to de-encode names when they are url-encoded, so you could use:

```
[pants & shorts] == [pants%20%26%20shorts]
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I have used (even though it might not be the best solution) is to change the & with text and after you retrieve it via $_GET you can change it back.

For example you would change the & for "andsign" before sending it:

```
 $your_var_without_and = str_replace("&", "andsign", $your_var);
```

And change it back after retrieving it:

```
 $your_var_without_and = $_GET['your_var_without_and'];

 $your_var = str_replace("andsign", "&", $your_var_without_and);
```

Answer (score 0):

When building URI query, either use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) or [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode):

```
$query = array('sex'=>'both', 'order'=>'newest', 'time'=>'all', 'type'=>'Pants & Shorts');
$url = 'http://localhost/clothes/?'.http_build_query($query);

$url = 'http://localhost/clothes/?sex=both&order=newest&time=all&type='.rawurlencode('Pants & Shorts');
```